# Painting video images on a TPaintBox in a VCL Form

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I have code that are to paint a BMP image on a TPaintBox on a VCL form in a C++ application.

Everything works fine as long as I only have one image to paint, on one form. When I create a second form, I get sporadic access violations.

The code is called from a thread and I'm using the Synchronize function in order to synchronize with the main VCL thread as this

```
void TCameraForm::loadImage(FramePtr frame)
{
    syncing s;
    s.aFrame = frame;
    s.theForm = this;

    //Synchronize with UI thread
    TThread::Synchronize(0, &s.fn);
}
```

In the code, a FramePtr is a shared pointer to one individual 'frame', holding a device dependent bitmap.

The syncing variable is a structure, holding the code for the actual painting:

```
//This is a trick to use VCL's TThread::Synchronize function "with parameters"
//Thanks to Mr. R. Lebeau for sharing this trick.
struct syncing
{
    FramePtr        aFrame;
    TCameraForm*    theForm;

    int tag;
    void __fastcall fn()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a device dependent bitmap
            BitMap aBitMap(aFrame);

            //Get the bitmap memory into a TMemoryStream
            TMemoryStream* ms = new TMemoryStream();
            int bytes = ms->Write(aBitmap.getBuffer()->mMemoryBuffer, aBitmap.getBuffer()->mBufferSize);
            ms->Position = 0;

            //Create a TPicture object that will be used for drawing on the paintbox
            TBitmap* tbm = new TBitmap();

            tbm->LoadFromStream(ms);
            TRect stretchedRect(getStretchedDimensions(tbm->Width, tbm->Height, theForm->PaintBox1->Width, theForm->PaintBox1->Height));
            theForm->PaintBox1->Canvas->StretchDraw(stretchedRect, tbm);

            delete ms;
            delete tbm;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            Log(lError) << "Exception occured in the CameraFrame sync function";
        }
    }
};
```

The debugger mainly stops on creation of the bitmap.

I'm using BCC builder 10.3.2 and the classic compiler.

The bitmap class looks like this:

Header

```
class BitMap 
{
    public:
                                BitMap(FramePtr aFrame);
                                BitMap(unsigned long width, unsigned long height, ColorCode c, ImageMemoryBuffer& buf);
        ImageMemoryBuffer*      getBuffer();
                                ~BitMap();
        bool                    write(const string& file);

    protected:
        unsigned int            mWidth;
        unsigned int            mHeight;
        ColorCode               mColorCode;
        ImageMemoryBuffer       mImageMemoryBuffer;
        bool                    create();
        bool                    release();
};
```

And CPP:

```
enum { THREE_CHANNEL    = 0xC,};
enum { BMP_HEADER_SIZE  = 54, };
enum { ALIGNMENT_SIZE   = 4, };

namespace ai
{

BitMap::BitMap(FramePtr aFrame)
:
mWidth(0),
mHeight(0),
mColorCode(ColorCodeMono8),
mImageMemoryBuffer()
{
    aFrame->GetImageSize(mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize);
    aFrame->GetWidth(mWidth);
    aFrame->GetHeight(mHeight);

    VmbPixelFormatType ePixelFormat = VmbPixelFormatMono8;
    aFrame->GetPixelFormat(ePixelFormat);
    if((ePixelFormat != VmbPixelFormatMono8) && (ePixelFormat != VmbPixelFormatRgb8))
    {
        throw(MVRException("Invalid pixel format: " + toString(ePixelFormat)));
    }

    mColorCode = (ePixelFormat == VmbPixelFormatRgb8) ? ColorCodeRGB24 : ColorCodeMono8;

    VmbUchar_t *pImage = NULL;
    if (aFrame->GetImage(pImage) != VmbErrorSuccess)
    {
        throw(MVRException("Failed \"getting\" image"));
    }

    mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer = (unsigned char*) pImage;
    if(!create())
    {
        Log(lError) << "There was an error creating the bitmap";
        throw(MVRException("Failed creating Bitmap"));
    }
}

BitMap::BitMap(unsigned long width, unsigned long height, ColorCode c, ImageMemoryBuffer& buf)
:
mWidth(width),
mHeight(height),
mColorCode(c),
mImageMemoryBuffer(buf)
{
    if(!create())
    {
        Log(lError) << "There was an error creating the bitmap";
        throw(MVRException("Failed creating bitmap"));
    }
}

BitMap::~BitMap()
{
    if(!release())
    {
        Log(lError) << "There was an error releasing the bitmap";
    }
}

ImageMemoryBuffer* BitMap::getBuffer()
{
    return &mImageMemoryBuffer;
}

bool BitMap::create()
{
    try
    {
        unsigned char   nNumColors;                     // Number of colors of our image
        unsigned char   nPadLength;                     // The padding we need to align the bitmap ALIGNMENT_SIZE
        unsigned long   nPaletteSize = 0;               // The size of the bitmap's palette
        unsigned long   nHeaderSize;                    // The size of the bitmap's header
        unsigned long   nFileSize;                      // The size of the bitmap file
        unsigned char*  pBitmapBuffer;                  // A buffer we use for creating the bitmap
        unsigned char*  pCurBitmapBuf;                  // A cursor to move over "pBitmapBuffer"
        unsigned char*  pCurSrc;                        // A cursor to move over the given buffer "pBuffer"
        unsigned long   px;                             // A single pixel for storing transformed color information
        unsigned long   x;                              // The horizontal position within our image
        unsigned long   y;                              // The vertical position within our image
        unsigned long   i;                              // Counter for some iteration

        // The bitmap header
        char fileHeader[14] = { 'B','M',                // Default
                                0,0,0,0,                // File size
                                0,0,0,0,                // Reserved
                                0,0,0,0 };              // Offset to image content

        char infoHeader[40] = { 40,0,0,0,               // Size of info header
                                0,0,0,0,                // Width
                                0,0,0,0,                // Height
                                1,0,                    // Default
                                0, 0 };                 // bpp

        if ( 0 == mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize || 0 == mWidth || 0 == mHeight )
        {
            Log(lError) << "Zero bitmap buffer, width ot height in Bitmap constructor";
            return false;
        }

        if ( mColorCode == (mColorCode & THREE_CHANNEL) )
        {
            nNumColors = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            nNumColors = 1;
        }

        // Bitmap padding always is a multiple of four Bytes. If data is not we need to pad with zeros.
        nPadLength = (mWidth * nNumColors) % ALIGNMENT_SIZE;
        if ( 0 != nPadLength )
        {
            nPadLength = ALIGNMENT_SIZE - nPadLength;
        }

        if ( ColorCodeRGB24 != mColorCode )
        {
            nPaletteSize = 256;
        }

        nHeaderSize     = BMP_HEADER_SIZE + nPaletteSize * 4;
        pBitmapBuffer   = (unsigned char*)malloc( nHeaderSize + mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize + (nPadLength * mHeight) );
        nFileSize       = nHeaderSize + mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize + (nPadLength * mHeight);

        // File size
        fileHeader[ 2]  = (char)(nFileSize);
        fileHeader[ 3]  = (char)(nFileSize >> 8);
        fileHeader[ 4]  = (char)(nFileSize >> 16);
        fileHeader[ 5]  = (char)(nFileSize >> 24);

        // Offset to image content
        fileHeader[10]  = (char)(nHeaderSize);
        fileHeader[11]  = (char)(nHeaderSize >> 8);
        fileHeader[12]  = (char)(nHeaderSize >> 16);
        fileHeader[13]  = (char)(nHeaderSize >> 24);

        // Width
        infoHeader[ 4]  = (char)(mWidth);
        infoHeader[ 5]  = (char)(mWidth >> 8);
        infoHeader[ 6]  = (char)(mWidth >> 16);
        infoHeader[ 7]  = (char)(mWidth >> 24);

        // Height (has to be negative for a top down image)
        infoHeader[ 8]  = (char)(-(long)mHeight);
        infoHeader[ 9]  = (char)(-(long)mHeight >> 8);
        infoHeader[10]  = (char)(-(long)mHeight >> 16);
        infoHeader[11]  = (char)(-(long)mHeight >> 24);

        // bpp
        infoHeader[14]  = 8 * nNumColors;

        // Image size
        infoHeader[20]  = (char)(mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize);
        infoHeader[21]  = (char)(mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize >> 8);
        infoHeader[22]  = (char)(mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize >> 16);
        infoHeader[23]  = (char)(mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize >> 24);

        // Palette size
        infoHeader[32]  = (char)(nPaletteSize);
        infoHeader[33]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 8);
        infoHeader[34]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 16);
        infoHeader[35]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 24);

        // Used colors
        infoHeader[36]  = (char)(nPaletteSize);
        infoHeader[37]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 8);
        infoHeader[38]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 16);
        infoHeader[39]  = (char)(nPaletteSize >> 24);

        // Write header
        pCurBitmapBuf   = pBitmapBuffer;
        memcpy(pCurBitmapBuf, fileHeader, 14);

        pCurBitmapBuf += 14;
        memcpy(pCurBitmapBuf, infoHeader, 40);

        pCurBitmapBuf += 40;
        for(i = 0; i < nPaletteSize; ++i)
        {
            pCurBitmapBuf[0] = (char)(i);
            pCurBitmapBuf[1] = (char)(i);
            pCurBitmapBuf[2] = (char)(i);
            pCurBitmapBuf[3] = 0;
            pCurBitmapBuf += 4;
        }

        // RGB -> BGR (a Windows bitmap is BGR)
        if(mColorCode == ColorCodeRGB24)
        {
            pCurSrc = (unsigned char*) mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer;
            for(y=0; y < mHeight; ++y, pCurBitmapBuf += nPadLength )
            {
                for (x = 0; x < mWidth; ++x, pCurSrc += 3, pCurBitmapBuf += 3)
                {
                    px = 0;
                    // Create a 4 Byte structure to store ARGB (we don't use A)
                    px = px | (pCurSrc[0] << 16) | (pCurSrc[1] << 8) | pCurSrc[2];
                    // Due to endianess ARGB is stored as BGRA
                    // and we only have to write the first three Bytes
                    memcpy( pCurBitmapBuf, &px, 3 );
                }

                // Add padding at the end of each row
                memset( pCurBitmapBuf, 0, nPadLength );
            }
            mColorCode = ColorCodeBGR24;
        }
        // Mono8
        else
        {
            if(nPadLength == 0)
            {
                memcpy( pCurBitmapBuf, mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer, mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize );
            }
            else
            {
                pCurSrc = (unsigned char*)mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer;
                for (y=0; y < mHeight; ++y, pCurSrc += mWidth * nNumColors)
                {
                    // Write a single row of colored pixels
                    memcpy( pCurBitmapBuf, pCurSrc, mWidth * nNumColors );
                    pCurBitmapBuf += mWidth * nNumColors;

                    // Write padding pixels
                    memset(pCurBitmapBuf, 0, nPadLength);
                    pCurBitmapBuf += nPadLength;
                }
            }
        }

        mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer = pBitmapBuffer;
        mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize = nFileSize;
        return true;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Exception in creation of bitmap create function";
        return false;
    }
}

bool BitMap::release()
{
    try
    {
        if (mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer != NULL && mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize > 0)
        {
            free(mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer);
            mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer = NULL;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool BitMap::write(const string& fName)
{
    if (mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(fName.c_str(), "wb");
    if(!file)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed opening file: " << fName;
        return false;
    }

    fwrite(mImageMemoryBuffer.mMemoryBuffer, 1, mImageMemoryBuffer.mBufferSize, file );
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

}
```

UPDATE: The above code works fine when executed by one thread. The problem occurs when several threads are involved. I have located the problem happening when the memcpy function is called in the creation of the bitmap (not the TBitmap), supporting this. So main problem is that the same memory is being manipulated by two or more threads at the same time.

For the above code, where would it be appropriate to incorporate a Mutex, in order to prevent the memory corruption? Or could one use another technique?

Comment: Do you _have_ you use the classic compiler? It's a pre C++11 compiler and starting a new project using pre C++11 seems like a bad choice. With the new compiler, you wouldn't have to resort to this trick.

Comment: Btw, is `BitMap` a `gdcm::Bitmap` or ... what is it?

Comment: I'm in the middle of updating to bcc32c, but not there yet. The VCL got new Synchronize functions for the bcc23c compiler?

The Bitmap class is from the Thirdparty code vendor (camera vendor Allied Vision). I'll add the code for that, as it is possible there are problems in it, but I can't tell. Perhaps one could use another Bitmap class?

Comment: I see. The new `Synchronize` accepts a functor, like a lambda, which means you can skip the `syncing` struct and just place the code directly in the call: `TThread::Synchronize( [&]() { ...your code that needs to be synchronized ... });`. What about using `TBitMap` from the VCL?

Comment: This would be more correct: `TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, [&]{ ... your code ... } );`. I forgot the `nullptr` for the static version.

Comment: I'm loading the Bitmap into a TBitmap, basically after dmping the frames memory into the Bitmap. Not sure how to go from the Frames memory directly into TBitMap, but I would prefer that? Will TBitmap figure out colorcodes, pixelformats etc?

Comment: Oh, I have no clue, but from what I remember (I haven't used it in a long time), TBitMap is a thin wrapper around the WinAPI BITMAP with a lot of convenience functions. It could be worth checking out.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson there is no need to use `TPicture` in this code, just use `TBitmap` directly. But the code still needs to be synced since `TBitmap` is not thread safe.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I simplified the code, but still having the same problems..

Comment: my experience is that no win api call related to rendering (GDI) or any visual stuff (windows) can be called outside wnd proc (no matter what). As IIRC VCL is based on winapi/GDI it applies to it too. The symptoms are just like you describe sporadic access violations or even other errors. My experience is that the errors are throwed by winapi calls in unrelated code to one which cause the problems... for example you access some VCL canvas in a thread (like take a screenshot of desktop, or render something to VCL window) and an error pops up 10 minutes latter while calling open file ...